# How to source a csh script from inside a bash script

Tags: shell-exec

My default shell is bash. I have set some environment variables in my .bashrc file.
I installed a program which use .cshrc file.  It contains the path to several cshell scripts.
When I run the following commands in the shell windows it works perfectly :

```
 exec csh

 source .cshrc

 exec bash
```

I have tried to put these commands in bash script, unfortunately it didn't work.
is there another way to write a script in order to get the same result as running commands from a shell windows.
I hope my question is now clear
Many thanks for any help

Comment: Just like you can't import C or Java code into your bash script. csh is a different language, so no. What is in the csh program that you need in bash?

Comment: the file is the '.cshrc' of a design_kit that contains variables to set and execute SEVERAL csh script (15 scripts) like : setenv PRODUCT_ROOT $CDS_INST_DIR  source $CDS_INST_DIR/uniopus.csh

Answer (score 1):

WARNING : don't put the following script in your .bashrc, it will reload bash and so reload .bashrc again and again (stopable with C-c anyway)
Use preferable this script in your kit/CDS stuff startup script.  (cadence presumably) 
WARNING 2 : if anything in your file2source fails, the whole 'trick' stops.

Call this script : cshWrapper.csh

```
#! /bin/csh
# to launch using 
# exec cshWrapper.csh file2source.sh
source $1
exec  $SHELL -i
```

and launch it using

```
exec ./cshWrapper.csh file2source.sh
```

it will : launch csh, source your file and came back to the same parrent bash shell

Example :

```
$> ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7065 pts/0    00:00:02 bash
$>exec ./cshWrapper.csh toggle.csh
file sourced
1
$> echo $$
7065
```

where in my case i use the file toggle.csh

```
#! /bin/csh
# source ./toggle.csh
if ! $?TOGGLE then
    setenv TOGGLE 0
endif

if ($?TOGGLE) then
    echo 'file sourced'
    if ($TOGGLE == 0) then
        setenv TOGGLE 1
    else
        setenv TOGGLE 0
    endif
endif
echo $TOGGLE
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

New proposal, since I faced another problem with exec.
**exec** kills whatever remains in the script, except if you force a fork by using a pipe after it `exec script |cat'. In such case if you have environment variable in the script, they are not *spread* back to the script itself, which is not what we want. The only solution I found is to use 3 files (let's call them for the example : **main.bash** that call **first.cshrc** and **second.sh**).

```
#! /bin/bash
#_main.bash_
exec  /bin/csh -c "source /path_to_file/cshrc; exec /bin/bash -i -c /path_to_file/second.sh"
# after exec nothing remains (like Attila the Hun)
# the rest of the script is in 'second.sh'
```

With that manner, i can launch in a single script call, an old cshrc design kit, and still process some bash command after, and finally launch the main program in bash (let say virtuoso)